# How to query embedded data documentDB to retrieve parent document

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

In DocumentDb, is it possible to search for child documents to get the parent documents?

```
public class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "locations")]
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        Locations = new List<Location>();
    }
}

public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "city")]
    public string City{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "state")]
    public string State{ get; set; } 

}
```

In the Document Explorer, I can see that I have one instance of this class structure like so:

```
{
  "id": "7",
  "name": "ACME Corp", 
  "location": [
    {
      "id": "c4202793-da55-4324-88c9-b9c9fe8f4b6c",
      "city": "newcity",
      "state": "ca" 
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "35",
  "name": "Another Corp", 
  "location": [
    {
      "id": "d33e793-da55-4324-88c9-b9c9fe8f4baa",
      "city": "newcity",
      "state": "ca" 
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to query the embedded data like where city = 'newcity' and state = 'ca'
but retrieve parent data? if I use SelectMany(x => x.Locations) to query for child then it will get Location data not the root(Customer) document.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to query the embedded data like where city = 'newcity' and state = 'ca' but retrieve parent data?

Yes, we may use **Join** to do that. More details please refer to [Advanced database concepts and SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#Advanced).

```
SELECT c.id as id ,c.name as name,l as location from customer c Join l in 
c.location where l.city = 'newcity' and l.state = 'ca'
```

Which returns

[image]

C# code demo:

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };
var customerQuery = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(
UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName),
                "SELECT c.id as id, c.name as name, l as location from customer c Join l in c.location where l.city = 'newcity' and l.state = 'ca'",
                queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

var customerList = new List<dynamic>();
while (customerQuery.HasMoreResults)
{

   customerList.AddRange(customerQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>().Result);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks much for the code and even screen capture!