# CosmosDB selfjoin via linq

Tags: .net, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document collection with documents that look like the following

```
{
  id: "123123541234"
  items: [
    {Name = "Item 1", Amount = 12.12},
    {Name = "Item 2", Amount = 4.00},
  ]
}
```

I can write a sql self joined query like the following to return what I want:

```
select c.id, i.Name, i.Amount
from c
join i in c.items
```

As you can see, my doc with the id `123123541234` would be duplicated, once for each item in the nested array, so the output looks like:

```
[ 
  {id = "123123541234", Name = "Item 1", Amount = 12.12 }, 
  {id = "123123541234", Name = "Item 2", Amount = 4.00} 
]
```

However, I'd like to use linq to write this query to keep my object references and type definition strong. I am failing to see how i can do this type of "flattening" via linq,

**TL;DR:** how do I do a self-join via linq to cosmosdb?

Comment: what is the ouput you need

Comment: I need 
[
 {id = "123123541234", Name="Item 1", Amount = 12.12 },
 {id="123123541234", Name="Item 2", Amount = 4.00}
]

Comment: is not it the same output you get already?

Comment: The intent is to use a linq statement, not a string query.  This is because if the model changes, I will get a compilation error, not a runtime error.

Comment: what do you mean by linq query?

Comment: The iqueriable interface

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332660/how-to-query-embedded-data-documentdb-to-retrieve-parent-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your types look something like this -

```
public class Container
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

public class FlattenedContainer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how you could do this -

```
var response = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Container>
            (
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(...),
                new FeedOptions { ... }
            )
            .SelectMany(c => c.Items
                .Select(i => new FlattenedContainer 
                { 
                    Id = c.Id, 
                    Name = i.Name, 
                    Amount = i.Amount 
                }))
            .AsDocumentQuery();

var results = new List<FlattenedContainer>();
while (response.HasMoreResults)
{
    results.AddRange(await response.ExecuteNextAsync<FlattenedContainer>());
}
```

Comment: ah, sneaky nesting! didn't think of doing it that way... does that get turned into the same query, or does it do the mapping in memory?

Comment: @NathanTregillus It ought to be the same query